# How can i add a listview item each time i press a button from another activity?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview item which contains 2 objects: 1 Textview(String) and 1 Switch button(Boolean). I'm using a custom adapter and a custom ArrayList to display these items and i want to add an item every time i press a button which comes from a different activity. The problem is that when i press the button to add a new listview item it replaces the old one with a new instead of adding a new row. I tried to use myadapter.notifydatasetchanged() to update the listview but didn't work because when  the activity changes, forgets the size of the Array and its like adding a new row from the beginning.

```
//Constructor
MyAdapter(Context context, List<Model> ModelArrayLista)
{
    super(context,0,ModelArrayLista);
    this.contexts = context;
    this.ModelArrayList = ModelArrayLista;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ModelArrayList.size();
}

public void remove(int position)
{
    ModelArrayList.remove(position);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
{
    View listItem = convertView;

    if(listItem == null)
    {
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(contexts).inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    }

    Model currentModel = ModelArrayList.get(position);

    TextView mtime = listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mtime.setText(currentModel.getTime());

    final Switch mswitch = listItem.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    mswitch.setChecked(currentModel.getSwitch_btn());

    final Intent disabled_intent = new Intent(contexts, Clock_Activity.class);
    final Intent enable_intent = new Intent(contexts,Clock_Activity.class);

    // Switch button - Turn on/Turn off
    mswitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        if(mswitch.isChecked())
        {
            enable_intent.putExtra("enable",en);
            contexts.startActivity(enable_intent);
        }
        else
        {
            disabled_intent.putExtra("disable", dis);
            contexts.startActivity(disabled_intent);
        }
        }
    });

    return listItem;
}

public class Model extends ArrayList<Model> {
private String time;
private boolean switch_btn;

public Model(String wra,Boolean switcher)
{
    this.time = wra;
    this.switch_btn = switcher;
}

public String getTime()
{
    return time;
}

public boolean getSwitch_btn()
{
    return switch_btn;
}
```

}

```
//OnCreate
    Initialisations();

    //get a String value that control our adapter
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    if(b!= null)
    {
        get_time = b.getString("time");
    }

    int num = intent.getIntExtra("number", 0);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    //call our custom adaptersS
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,list);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    //get a boolean value that controls our adapter
    showthelist = intent.getBooleanExtra("keyList",false);
    if(showthelist)
    {
        list.add(new Model(get_time,true));
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    if(num == 1)
    {
        list.set(0,new Model(get_time,false));
    }
```

Comment: Currently you're not saving the existing data anywhere.  You'll need to save the existing rows to disk (a SQLite database would work), or save in memory outside of the activity that shows the list.  Then load the existing data each time the activity loads.  You'll also want to save the new row to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is not possible to keep data in a list if the activity is destroyed.

You can implement either of these 2 solutions,

> 1. Create SQLite database or Shared Preference to save your list so
>      every time you create an instance, your constructor reads database
>      and loads it into your list view.
> 2. If your data is not that significant (i.e. if you don't want it after app is closed), then keep the activity intact and stack other
>      activities on top of it. Below is pseudo code to do it.

```
    ActivityIntact{
    //on some button click
    startActivity(NewActivity);
    }

    NewActivity{
    //Add a close button or just finish this activity anyhow you want
    closeButton.setOnclickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
            NewActivity.this.finish(); //This is important to destroy this activity
            }
    });

}
```